# Updating object value from prototype function

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm trying to do this:

```
String.prototype.clear = function(){
    alert(this.value);
    this = ''; // I want to set value to '' here
}

var temp = 'Hello';
temp.clear();// After this step temp should be ''
```

But I'm getting invalid left hand assignment error. and I found this question as reference, but it's not really what I want.
I also find out that 'this' is Immutable.

So, is there any way to do my task? I'm not using it any where. Just playing around.
Thanks.

Comment: Strings are immutable... string objects too.

Comment: You should not be messing with native object prototypes.

Comment: It's easier to do just `temp = ''` )))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set String via String.prototype function without return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370511/set-string-via-string-prototype-function-without-return)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class called MyMutableString like:

```
function MyMutableString(s) {
   this.string = s;
   this.clear = function() {
      this.string = "";
   }
}
```

Now you create an instance and use it like like:

```
var s = new MyMutableString("my str");
s.clear(); // makes string stored inside object `s` empty
console.log(s.string);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it short:

You can't.

Strings are immutable. Once it is made, a string can never be changed.

You have to set your string to an empty string to "clear" it

```
var str = "String";
str='';
```

*Note that this won't change the string but sets `str` to a new Instance of a String, the old one gets garbage collected*

It is even shorter then calling a Prototypes method of the Object which would do exactly the same. *And* you don't have to temper with the native Objects prototypes

---

Edit - Thx for pointing that out [Florian Margaine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973642/1487756)

If you have many occurences of setting empty Strings and might change your future "definition" of clearing,  you could either use a funciton that returns `` or a empty String

```
function clearString () {
    return ''
}
var str = "Asd"
var str = clearString()
```

Or simply Set a variable to an empty String

```
var emptyString = ''
var str = "Asd"
str = emptyString //''
```

Now if you want to change `''` into `null` or `undefined`

`var emptyString = null`

Which would work as well, since primitive data types are being passed as value and not by reference

But i would suggest not modifying an Objects prototype for something like this

Answer (score 0):

what about a object copy like this?

```
String.prototype.clear = function(){
    alert(this);
    return '';
}


var temp = 'Hello';
var newTemp = temp.clear();
alert(newTemp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from creating a wrapper, the best way is to just go with the functional way.

```
String.prototype.clear = function() {
    return '';
};

var t = 'hello';
t = t.clear();
```

Why not just doing `t = '';`, you say? Well, clearing today might mean putting `''`, but it might mean putting `null` tommorrow. Having a single point to change it might be worth it. Or not at all.

Comment: Why do you need to add a prototype method that only rteturns ''
you could just set `t = ''`

Comment: @Glutamat yeah, I'd do that. But a method can be convenient. Plus, clearing today might mean putting `''`, but it might have to mean putting `null` tommorrow.

Comment: Thats right, nice point, you wouldn't have to change every occurence of `t = ''` to `t = null`, but you could use a simple function or even a variable to return `''` theres no to add methods to `String.prototype` since you can't clear it whit only a method call like `t.clear()` but either way have to redefine it `t = t.clear`
=)