# Formatting input value and restrictions for user (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, number-formatting

How I could create an `<input type="text" />` with following restrictions for the User and formatting extensions, namely using JavaScript or jQuery?

- The User can use only numeric chars. Nothing else.
- The User can't delete the dot. Never. Is it possible? If it isn't and the user will remove the dot, how to give the dot back automatically on losing focus?
- On blur (lose focus), if the decimal places are empty, script will fill it with zeros (↓).
- I need this pattern for view: **X XXX.XX**
  (`toFixed(2)` I can use for two decimal places, but I don't know way to separate string according pattern).

Certainly you've noticed, that the text field should be the price. The script should operate on multiple input fields with class "pr-dec".

```
<input type="text" class="pr-dec" size="8" value="0.00" />
```

Thanks a lot for any help, **your time** and suggestions.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAekS/)** can facilitate it.

Comment: This is not "do all the work for me forum". Show us the code you have came up with and we will help you.

Comment: @ Matúš víš, na těchhle bodech jsem se zastavil, jsem začátečník a nevím si rady, stojím na tom celou noc :/

Comment: So just a small navigation, check  jQuery.isNumeric() function, it can help you with lot of related number validation.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you tell me something about jQuery Formatter?
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/

Comment: Not really, I do not have any experience with that. Most of the time I am using hand written regular expressions or $(this).keypress(function(event){}) character validation

Comment: I understand. I tried to use it, but it had confuse with the current code and it did not work.

Comment: Post the malfunctioning code and we can work on solution.

Comment: I'm scared about this 8-D

Comment: But thank you for your proposal and your responses. I will try hard(er).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems you need to solve.
Break them down into smaller chunks and tackle it from there.

### Only numbers

You could watch the field (check out [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)) for a change and then delete any character that's not part of the set `[\d]` or `[0-9]`, but that could get messy.
A better idea might be to watch for a `keydown` event and only allow the [keys that represent numbers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html).

### The Dot

Trying to dynamically stop the user from deleting the dot is messy, so let's just focus on adding it back in when the field is blurred.
That's pretty easy, right? Just check for a `.` and if there isn't one, append ".00" to the end of the field.

### Decimal Places

This is really the same problem as above. You can use `.indexOf('.')` to determine if the dot is present, and if it is, see if there are digits after it. If not, append "00" if so, make sure there's 2 digits, and append a "0" if there's only 1.

### String Pattern

This could really be solved any number of ways, but you can reuse your search for the decimal place from above to split the string into "Full Dollar" and "Decimal" parts.
Then you can use simple counting on the "Full Dollar" part to add spaces.  Check out the [Javascript split and splice functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20817684/597122) to insert characters at various string indexes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for great process suggestion, surely will check mentioned functions. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate says he said:
"Matus know the těchhle point I stopped, I'm a beginner and do not know what I stand on it all night"

Sounds like you need to read up on some JavaScript and jQuery tutorials.  I began with something like this: [jQuery for Absolute Beginners: The Complete Series](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series--net-2134)

Really hope this helps.

Comment: I think the navigation from Matúš is something what I need. But i appreciate your answer and will check it.