# Take random letters out from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, substr

I want to remove 3 RANDOM letters from a string.

I can use something like `substr()` or `slice()` function but it won't let me take the random letters out.

Here is the demo of what I have right now.

http://jsfiddle.net/euuhyfr4/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remove a random 3 letter sequence from the string? such as abc'123' or a'bc1'23 where the '' denotes whats removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "hello world";
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    str = removeRandomLetter(str);
}
alert(str);

function removeRandomLetter(str) {
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*str.length);
    return str.substring(0, pos)+str.substring(pos+1);
}
```

If you want to replace 3 random charc with other random chars, you can use 3 times this function:

```
function substitute(str) { 
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*str.length); 
    return str.substring(0, pos) + getRandomLetter() + str.substring(pos+1); 
} 
function getRandomLetter() { 
    var  letters="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"; 
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length); 
    return letters.charAt(pos); 
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that instead of removing the 3 letters... replace any 3 letters of the word with 3 random letters?

Comment: Yes, of course.
`function subsctitute(str) {
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*str.length);
    return str.substring(0, pos)+getRandomLetter()+str.substring(pos+1);
}
function getRandomLetter() { 
 var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length);
return letters.charAt(pos);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string to an array, [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) random items, and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) back to a string:

```
var arr = str.split('');
for(var i=0; i<3; ++i)
    arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
str = arr.join('');
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that instead of removing the 3 letters... replace any 3 letters of the word with 3 random letters?

Comment: @user4756836 Yes: `arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)] = randomLetter()`. The definition of `randomLetter` will vary depending on what characters you want (a-z, A-Z, digits, latin1, ...).

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "cat123",
    amountLetters = 3,
    randomString = "";

for(var i=0; i < amountLetters; i++) {
  randomString += str.substr(Math.floor(Math.random()*str.length), 1);
}
alert(randomString);
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/euuhyfr4/7/

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that instead of removing the 3 letters... replace any 3 letters of the word with 3 random letters?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21350614/2302862) states that

> It is faster to slice the string twice [...] than using a split followed by a join [...]

Therefore, while [**Oriol**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879693/30433) works perfectly fine, I believe a faster implementation would be:

```
function removeRandom(str, amount)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        var max = str.length - 1;
        var pos = Math.round(Math.random() * max);
        str = str.slice(0, pos) + str.slice(pos + 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

See also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euuhyfr4/10/).

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that instead of removing the 3 letters... replace any 3 letters of the word with 3 random letters?

Answer (score 1):

you can shuffle characters in your string then remove first 3 characters

```
var str = 'congratulations';

String.prototype.removeItems = function (num) {
    var a = this.split(""),
        n = a.length;

    for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a.join("").substring(num);
}

alert(str.removeItems(3));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that instead of removing the 3 letters... replace any 3 letters of the word with 3 random letters?

Answer (score -1):

You can use split method without any args.
This would return all chars as a array.

Then you can use any randomiser function as described in [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) , then use that position to get the character at that position.

Have a look @ my implementation here

```
var str = "cat123";
var strArray = str.split("");

function getRandomizer(bottom, top) {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
    }
alert("Total length " + strArray.length);
var nrand = getRandomizer(1, strArray.length);
alert("Randon number between range 1 - length of string " + nrand);

alert("Character @ random position " + strArray[nrand]);
```

Code @ here https://jsfiddle.net/1ryjedq6/

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so that instead of removing the 3 letters... replace any 3 letters of the word with 3 random letters?

Comment: @user4756836 can you be more specific? you want to replace random chars with random positions?

Comment: I want to replace 3 random chosen letters from the word with ANY random letter from a-z. For example, if the word is Hello Kitty... it may change to Hezls Kilty

Comment: Yeah it very simple. Define a array with all English alphabets. From the random number generator generate 2 numbers. Num1 will be the position of the string, where the char needs to be replaced and Num2 will be index to the array of english alphabets. (or) re-use the same number again to pick up a new char from the alphabets array.