# Node js remove sensitive data from object before sending it

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, array-splice

I want to remove some sensitive data from the array before sending to the client (to render all the users), but for some reason I can't actually remove them! I need to remove some usernames, passwords, emails etc. Is there something with splice() ? Thank you for helping me!

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){ Users.find{}, function(err, usersArray){
  for(var a = 0; a < usersArray.length; a++){
    usersArray[a].userData.username.splice(0, 1); // here's my error
    usersArray[a].userData.email.splice(0, 1); // end here
    usersArray[a].userData.password.splice(0, 1); // and also here
    ...
  }
  res.render('users.ejs', {
    // and the variables go here...
  })

}
```

By the way, the error I get is "TypeError: undefined is not a function". Thanks again!

Comment: Strings do not have a `splice` method, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817618/is-there-a-splice-method-for-strings

Comment: @LeartS I presume the `username`, etc. objects are arrays of usernames, etc., not strings. (It wouldn't make sense to chop off the first char of a string to censor something, anyway.)

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't tell us what the structure of the entries in `usersArray` is?

Comment: @Doorknob冰 I think you presume wrong, the error suggests he's trying to use `splice` on an object that does not have the `splice` method. The array is `usersArray` and he gets the single user object by indexing it.

Comment: @LeartS Ah, you're right; I didn't see the last line of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess that you want to remove `username`, `email`, and `password` entirely. If so, you're looking for `delete`, which removes properties from objects:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){ Users.find{}, function(err, usersArray){
  for(var a = 0; a < usersArray.length; a++){
    var userData = usersArray[a].userData;
    delete userData.username;
    delete userData.email;
    delete userData.password;
    ...
  }
  res.render('users.ejs', {
    // and the variables go here...
  })
}
```

If those propeties are *non-configurable*, `delete` can't remove them, and you have to make do with setting their values to `undefined`:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){ Users.find{}, function(err, usersArray){
  for(var a = 0; a < usersArray.length; a++){
    var userData = usersArray[a].userData;
    userData.username = undefined;
    userData.email = undefined;
    userData.password = undefined;
    ...
  }
  res.render('users.ejs', {
    // and the variables go here...
  })
}
```

If they're both non-configurable *and* non-writable, you'll have to create replacement objects instead.

**Live Example using `delete`:**

```js
var usersArray = [{
  userData: {
    name: "User 1", // Something to have left after we remove the others
    username: "user1",
    email: "user1@example.com",
    password: "pa$$word"
  }
}, {
  userData: {
    name: "User 2",
    username: "user2",
    email: "user2@example.com",
    password: "pa$$word"
  }
}, {
  userData: {
    name: "User 3",
    username: "user3",
    email: "user3@example.com",
    password: "pa$$word"
  }
}];
snippet.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(usersArray, null, 2));
for (var a = 0; a < usersArray.length; a++) {
  var userData = usersArray[a].userData;
  delete userData.username;
  delete userData.email;
  delete userData.password;
}
snippet.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(usersArray, null, 2));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

**Live Example with non-configurable properties using `undefined`:**

```js
function makeUserData(name, username, email, password) {
  var ud = {name: name};
  Object.defineProperty(ud, "username", {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: username
  });
  Object.defineProperty(ud, "email", {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: email
  });
  Object.defineProperty(ud, "password", {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: password
  });
  return ud;
}
var usersArray = [{
  userData: makeUserData("User 1", "user1", "user1@example.com", "pa$$word")
},{
  userData: makeUserData("User 2", "user2", "user2@example.com", "pa$$word")
},{
  userData: makeUserData("User 3", "user3", "user3@example.com", "pa$$word")
}];
snippet.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(usersArray, null, 2));
for (var a = 0; a < usersArray.length; a++) {
  var userData = usersArray[a].userData;
  delete userData.username;
  delete userData.email;
  delete userData.password;
}
snippet.log("After delete: " + JSON.stringify(usersArray, null, 2));
for (var a = 0; a < usersArray.length; a++) {
  var userData = usersArray[a].userData;
  userData.username = undefined;
  userData.email = undefined;
  userData.password = undefined;
}
snippet.log("After assigning undefined: " + JSON.stringify(usersArray, null, 2));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I have the code like this, it seems to run with no errors, but it still won't work! I also console.log() the array and it still has all the sensitive data in it. Just for clarification userData is an array, the rest of them (username, email, password etc) are just strings that I have to remove.

Comment: @JimTheGreek: Don't know what to tell you, if those properties exist on those objects and they're not non-configurable, `delete` will remove them. If they're non-configurable, you can set them to `undefined`.

Comment: @JimTheGreek: And if they're non-writable, you'll have to create whole new objects with just the properties you want.