# Best way to slice a string that is stored in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, object

I am trying to slice a string that is stored in an object, but I am getting an error because I believe you cant use `.slice()` on values stored in an object.

`paidData.id` contains the `id` of the invoice and is a string, which I have confirmed with `typeof`

```js
function paidCard(paidData) {

    // Converting epoch seconds to human readable date
    const invoiceDue = moment.unix(data.due_date);
    const invoiceDueConverted = invoiceDue.format(' MMMM Do YYYY');

    // Executing the function to convert amout due.
    const amountDue = decimalInsert(data.amount_due);
      const test = paidData.id; // <--- Logged this to console and it exists
      const result = test.slice(5) // <--- Cant read properties of undefined error here
  
    
    // Shows a notification when data from database has been loaded
    return(
      <InvoiceCard
      paid={true}
      invoiceStatusIconContainerColor='rgba(2,49,7,0.7)'
      invoiceStatusIconColor='#29DA7A'
      invoiceStatusText={paidData.status}
      customerName={paidData.customer_name}
      invoiceId={paidData.id}
      invoiceIdTextColor='#5C5C5C'
      customerEmail={paidData.customer_email}
      customerAddress={paidData.customer_address}
      invoiceAmount={amountDue}
      invoiceDateIconStatusColor='#FA3C3C'
      invoiceDateText={invoiceDueConverted}
    />
    );
  };
  let invoiceData = []
  let paidInvoiceData = []
  
  // Render the invoices by mapping through state.
  if(data && paidData && Array.isArray(data) && Array.isArray(paidData)) {
     invoiceData = data.map(card);
     paidInvoiceData =  paidData.map(paidCard);
```

**Error I am getting**

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
```

Comment: You'll need to post an example of your code for concrete help, but a string is just a string regardless of where it's stored.

Comment: I added the code. You can see that I am mapping over the paidData and rendering an invoice component for each object. I also tried to stringify and that didn't work as well

Comment: This looks more like a component lifecycle issue than a string method issue.

Comment: I posted the error I am getting. Do you think its possible the method is trying to run on something that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Yes, I do, but creating an array of precomposed components the way you are is bound to lead to problems as it doesn't appear to exist within the context of a meaningful tree of components

Comment: Ran the slice outside of the component and still ran into the error. I ran the slice on just the object itself and it ran. So I am not sure why its running on the object itself and not the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the string is located (in an array, in an object, or in a variable). You can slice it normally:

```
var object = {id: '12345'};
console.log(object.id.slice(0,3)); // returns 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `.slice()` method on any string, even if it is stored in an object. For example, this would be valid JS code:

```js
const obj = { str: "StackOverflow is good" }
console.log(str.slice(0,12)) // "StackOverflow"
```

However, `.slice()` does *not* mutate the string it was called on. JS does not provide a `.splice()` (mutating) for strings, so you'll have to polyfill it. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817618/is-there-a-splice-method-for-strings)  for a good polyfill.