# How to change the key pressed in an input tag using dispatchEvent()?

Tags: javascript, html

let's say I have an html input and I would like that whenever someone press a key or combination of keys while the input is focused, it input a different character where the caret is positioned.

for instance let's say I have a site with virtual keyboard French that is compatible with the English keyboard. But I also give the user the ability to use custom keyboard shortcut to input French characters (those with accent let's say).

How would one do that using ES6's dispatchEvent & KeyboardEvent Object?

Here is what I tried (the code uses JIS Layout Keyboard):

```js
let isShiftPressed = false;
let isControlPressed = false;
let isNonConvertPressed = false;
let isConvertPressed = false;

const kbdDown = function(event) {
  if (event.code === "ShiftLeft" || event.code === "ShiftRight") {
    isShiftPressed = true;
  }
  if (event.code === "ControlLeft" || event.code === "ControlRight") {
    isControlPressed = true;
  }
  if (event.code === "NonConvert" || event.code === "NonConvert") {
    isNonConvertPressed = true;
  }

  console.log("{ code : " + event.code + ", key : " + event.key + "}");

  if (event.code === "KeyA" && isShiftPressed && isNonConvertPressed) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const keyPressedEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
      key: "X",
      code: "KeyX"
    })

    event.target.dispatchEvent(keyPressedEvent);
  }
}

const kbdUp = function(event) {
  if (event.code === "ShiftLeft" || event.code === "ShiftRight") {
    isShiftPressed = false;
  }
  if (event.code === "ControlLeft" || event.code === "ControlRight") {
    isControlPressed = false;
  }
  if (event.code === "NonConvert" || event.code === "NonConvert") {
    isNonConvertPressed = false;
  }
}

const registerkbdHandler = function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("keydown", kbdDown);
  element.addEventListener("keyup", kbdUp);
}

registerkbdHandler(document.querySelector("input"));
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

When I focus on the input field and press **NonConvert + Shift + A** it outputs the following on the browser console:

**output-listing : console**

> { code : NonConvert, key : NonConvert} script.js:21
>
> { code : ShiftLeft, key : Shift} script.js:21
>
> { code : KeyA, key : A} script.js:21
>
> { code : KeyX, key : X}

Clearly the keyboard event is getting dispatched but the input text field doesn't show any new character.

Comment: Why not just use the value" `if (event.code === "KeyA" && isShiftPressed && isNonConvertPressed) {
    event.preventDefault(); event.target.value = 'カ' }`

Comment: @mplungjan if I am not mistaken the `value` property will change the entire value of the field. Also let's say I wrote "éleves" (which is a mispelled orthographe of "élèves" which is French for "pupil") then I move the caret (cursor) back to the "e" so I can replace it with and "e acute", I hit backspace and press they key combo. I would have to do some insane code gymansitc to know exactly where the cursor is and som other gymanstic to replace the value so that it includes the "e acute". Also I won't be able to use that if for instance I want to use an contenteditable div.

Comment: Ok, fair enough... Doable but not convenient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update: full, custom example:**

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById('myInput');

// 1. Intercept `keydown` event
inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  const {shiftKey, keyCode} = event

  if (shiftKey && keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) {
    
    const {selectionStart, selectionEnd, value} = inputElement
    const selectionLength = selectionEnd - selectionStart;

    // 2a. Manually adjust the value of the input
    inputElement.value = spliceString(value, selectionStart, selectionLength, 'X');

    // 2b. Manually adjust cursor position
    inputElement.selectionStart = inputElement.selectionEnd = selectionStart + 1
    
    // 3. Prevent default event behavior
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/21350614/117030
function spliceString(str, index, count, add) {
  var ar = str.split('');
  ar.splice(index, count, add);
  return ar.join('');
}
```

```html
<p>This input will insert 'X' if <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key is down:</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

---

I accomplished [something similar](https://github.com/Leftium/bangtastic/blob/a4dfce5e46dcccabef82754429c5a86108a20ee3/src/routes/%2Bpage.svelte#L29-L48) for my app by:

1. Intercepting the `keydown` event.
2. Manually adjusting the value of the input. (And cursor position if necessary)
3. Calling `event.preventDefault()` only if the input was manually adjusted (otherwise let the default behavior occur.)

Live demo: https://bangtastic.vercel.app/

- If space is pressed, it is turned into `!` in certain cases.
- Otherwise input is accepted as normal
- In the linked code, `value` is bound to the input's value.

Note: this must happen on `keydown`; other events like `input` and `keyup` are too late.

Comment: Your code, from what I've seen from the source, is appending at the end of the string in the input,  instead of wherever the caret is from what I've tested and the source code I read. maybe I should have made it clear  (I made it clear in the comment section only unfortunately and I apologize). See comment on my original post.

Comment: @PaikuHan: Forgive me, my app only needed append at the end, but I thought it was straight-forward to modify it to insert in the middle. It might be tricky for you to preserve the cursor, so I have updated my answer with a full custom example.

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought saving and restoring caret position might work. It did but my final solution using `document.execCommand` is better because it mimics actual typing, instead of programmatically changing value of the `input` element. This would allow you even to ctrl+z.

The event used is `keydown` which is cancelable and also makes sense because you want the *typing* to be changed.

This example replaces 'a' with 'b' but don't forget to add your logic for detecting control keys and combinations.

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById('myInput');

inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'a') {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'b');
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="myInput">Type 'a' to be replaced with 'b': </label>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

UPDATE (2024): `execCommand` is deprecated. You can still try to save/restore caret position using `inputElement.selectionStart`, `inputElement.selectionEnd` and `inputElement.setSelectionRange`

Comment: your code works mighty fine. I upvoted it. but didn't accept it as the correct answer yet as it does not use `dispatchEvent()` (which is what I asked in my question. If nobody comes up with a good answer that uses `dispatchEvent()` (or explain why it is not doable), then I will gladly accept your...

**EDIT** Disregard what I said. I should have been more careful and I sincerely apologize. execCommand is obsolete/deprecated. I had completely forgotten about that until I tried to refresh my memory on how to use it. You will keep the upvote but I cannot accept this answer.